# Which JDK is IntelliJ IDEA using?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-13, intellij-14

I have several JDKs installed on my mac. How do I find out the JDK version being used by IntelliJ IDEA JVM to run itself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Click on Help > About, and IntelliJ will report both its version and the version of Java it's currently running on.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a mac, but you may have a look at script under `$IDEA_HOME/bin/idea.sh`, they try in order: IDEA_JDK, ../jre, JDK_HOME, JAVA_HOME, "java" in PATH, on Darwin(OSX) they also try use `/usr/libexec/java_home`

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to find the one used at runtime.